# What causes the "control.registerOnChange is not a function" error

Tags: forms, angular

I have a form using the reactive form approach. The form is created as follow in my pug:

```
form([formGroup]='form', novalidate='', (ngSubmit)='postSurvey(form.value, form.valid)')
```

Everything works fine except when I try to change the form (which is a `FormArray`) in the javascript part. I get the following error:

```
EXCEPTION: Error in http://localhost:8080/app/components/fillForm.template.html:0:326 caused by: control.registerOnChange is not a function
core.umd.js:3497 TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function
    at setUpControl (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:1634:17)
    at eval (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:4752:25)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at FormGroupDirective._updateDomValue (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:4747:29)
    at FormGroupDirective.ngOnChanges (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:4616:22)
    at Wrapper_FormGroupDirective.ngDoCheck (/ReactiveFormsModule/FormGroupDirective/wrapper.ngfactory.js:30:18)
    at View_FillFormComponent2.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/FillFormComponent/component.ngfactory.js:275:32)
    at View_FillFormComponent2.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12592:18)
    at View_FillFormComponent2.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12739:48)
    at ViewContainer.detectChangesInNestedViews (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12850:41)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_FillFormComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/FillFormComponent/component.ngfactory.js:64:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12592:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12739:48)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.internalDetectChanges (http://localhost:8080/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12577:22)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_FillFormComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (/AppModule/FillFormComponent/host.ngfactory.js:29:19)
```

My code to change the form is quite complex and I can't simplify it or reproduce it in a plunker. More than finding directly the solution (it's too difficult with so little details), I would like to understand what this error means? And what might cause this error.

I have figured out that the error occurs at `[formGroup]='form'` in my HTML.

Any suggestion will help.

**Update** I have filed an issue on angular github [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/26998) and have proposed a fix [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/27246) The plunker to reproduce the issue is [here](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/vh1HCo2WrwNgr95G?open=lib%2Fapp.ts&deferRun=1)

Answer (score 126):

Yes, that error message is a bit cryptic, but if you use **FormBuilder**, you would see this when you added a control to **FormGroup** in your component and named it *"A"*, but then either forgot to add input with *formControlName="A"* to your template, or *formControlName* for the intended input is not *A*, or empty, or not present.

Basically, it says: "I cannot match the control I have in FormGroup to the control in the template".

Comment: Very helpful note.

Answer (score 89):

I came across looking for a solution to the similar issue and then found a solution myself. 
My issue was the following. I had a form like this

```
form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
  status: new FormArray([])
});
```

Initially it was represented by the list of checkboxes for each status on the template. And then I created a custom component to represent `status` selector and used it in template like so

```
<status-selector [formControlName]="'status'"></status-selector>
```

The problem is that `formControlName` must point to `FormControl` instance, but actually it was pointing to a `FormArray` instance. So, changing to `status: new FormControl([])` fixed this issue for me.

Comment: I tried this in my code. And it works. but I'm failing to understand why it worked. The 'status' field is holding an array of objects for you, correct?

Comment: @AngelaPan no, FormArray is an array of FormControl-s, not onbjects.

Comment: For me I had to change [formControlName] to [formGroupName], but I got idea from this answer. thanks.

Comment: @BenKim - that was my issue. I think Vladimir could have used formArrayName too

Comment: For me it was a having formControlName for a FormGroup

Comment: formControlName is for "FormControl".
formArrayName is for "FormArray"

Answer (score 59):

In my case this error was thrown because I was using `FormControlName` instead of `FormArrayName` to bind to a `FormArray` in my template.

My component code:

```
public form = new FormGroup({
   ...
   checkboxes: new FormArray([....])
})
```

My template code that threw error:

```
<input type="checkbox" formControlName="checkboxes" />
```

Fix:

```
<input type="checkbox" formArrayName="checkboxes" />
```

Answer (score 17):

I have also encountered this error when mixing template driven with reactive driven approaches (by mistake):

```
<input #inputCtrl
       [formControl]="inputCtrl"
/>
```

`inputCtrl` was properly defined in the component. Of course, `#inputCtrl` must be scrapped in order to work (it was hard to see when input had about 10 attributes).

Answer (score 9):

In my case the error occurred when the formControl name was same as a template variable on the page. For example

```
<select id="status" [formControl]="userStatus">...</select>

<form-status #userStatus ></form-status> //matching template variable name
```

Answer (score 6):

```
this.extensionForm = this._fb.group({
      id: [''],
      category: [12],
      extensions: new FormArray([]),
      priority: ['', []],
    });
    formArray.push(this.extensionForm);
```

> Note :-   error occurs because of you have used formControlName
> where you declare formArray,   you must use formArrayName instead

```
<input type="text" formControlName="extensions" />

simple solution: 

<input type="checkbox" formArrayName="extensions" />
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case I got the error when I used `formControlName` in the template when actual form model was a FormGroup instance. Changing to `formControlGroup` helped.

Answer (score 3):

If have defined a FormArray field in your form, note that you do NOT need to label it with formControlName="". You need to handle the input and validation in other ways (setters, getters, functions), but will definitely get an error if you try to assign formControlName to a FormArray!

Answer (score 3):

This error also appears when we use a reactive form inside `ng-template` in conjunction with `*ngIf`.

To avoid this use `ng-container` and do not use `ngElse`.

Answer (score 3):

In my case the issue was that I was referring to something as a [`FormGroup`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) instead of a [`FormControl`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) with an object as the value.

This was my initial, faulty code:

```
formArray.push(
    new FormGroup({
        value: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        description: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
        tags: new FormArray([], Validators.minLength(1)),
    }),
);
```

and in the template, I was using a component (`custom-form-component` in this example) which implements [`ControlValueAccessor`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor):

```html
<li *ngFor="let item of items; let itemIndex = index"
    <custom-form-component [formGroupName]="itemIndex"></custom-form-component>
</li>
```

This group is handled in the `custom-form-component` component which I'm using, therefore instead a `FormControl` should be used:

```
formArray.push(
    new FormControl({
        value: '',
        description: '',
        tags: [],
    }),
);
```

and in the template, use [`formControlName`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName) instead of [`formGroupName`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroupName):

```html
<li *ngFor="let item of items; let itemIndex = index"
    <custom-form-component [formControlName]="itemIndex"></custom-form-component>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have moved a control element outside the group in the template.

OK:

```
<div formGroupName="passwordForm">
     Password: <input type="password" formControlName="password">
     Confirm: <input type="password" formControlName="confirmPassword">
</div>
```

Not OK:

```
Password: <input type="password" formControlName="password">
<div formGroupName="passwordForm">
     Confirm: <input type="password" formControlName="confirmPassword">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Angular I had the same problem when I tried to build my own form component and forgot to implement the ControlValueAccessor interface:

```
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-country-select',
  templateUrl: './country-select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./country-select.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CountrySelectComponent),
      multi: true,
    },
  ],
})
export class CountrySelectComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges, ControlValueAccessor {

  propagateChange = (_: any) => { }; // ControlValueAccessor 

  private internalValue: string | undefined;

  get value(): string | undefined {
    return this.internalValue;
  }
  set value(value: string | undefined) {
    this.internalValue = value;
    this.propagateChange(value);
  }

  // some other methods here

  // implementing the ControlValueAccessor interface with these three methods
  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    if (obj) {
      this.value = obj;
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.propagateChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    // throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this when I accidentally reset the value of my form control property instead of using the `.setValue()` method.

Wrong

`control = new FormControl([1])... control = []`

Right

`control = new FormControl([1])... control.setValue([])`

Answer (score 0):

Adding in what was causing it in my situation.

`.ts` file,

```
...

export class MyComponent {
  dateFrom = new FormControl(new Date());
...
}
```

`.html` file,

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dateFrom" [formControl]="dateFrom"
      placeholder="Min date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dateFrom"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #dateFrom ></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Basically, within the template file, it didn't know which 'dateFrom' to choose, and chooses the one in the template file, which isn't the `FormControl` in my typescript file, it's the `mat-datepicker` element in the template file.

Renaming the FormControl to `dateFromCtrl` fixed this,

i.e.

```
...

export class MyComponent {
  dateFromCtrl = new FormControl(new Date());
...
}
```

`.html` file,

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dateFrom" [formControl]="dateFromCtrl"
      placeholder="Min date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dateFrom"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #dateFrom ></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Works as expected.

Kodos to VS Code for figuring this out. I got pushed this direction by doing a Cmd + Click on the initial 'dateFrom' at `[formControl]="dateFrom"`, and it pointed me to the `mat-datepicker` element.

Answer (score 0):

to me it happened when I used same `[formControl]="carBrand"` and `[matAutocomplete]="carBrandAuto"` from my autocomplete input

I changed this

FROM:

```
...
<input
  [formControl]="carBrand"
  [matAutocomplete]="carBrand"
>
<mat-autocomplete matAutocomplete #carBrand="matAutocomplete">
...
```

TO

```
...
<input
  [formControl]="carBrand"
  [matAutocomplete]="carBrandAuto"
>
<mat-autocomplete matAutocomplete #carBrandAuto="matAutocomplete">
...
```

Answer (score 0):

For future readers, my problem was a simple one and it causes **TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function**

When I was creating the new FormGroup I accidentally used FormGroup instead of FormControl

```html
  myForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    lname: new FormGroup({}),
    fnam: new FormGroup({}),
    date: new FormGroup({}),
  });
```

It should have been this:

```html
  myForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    lname: new FormControl(''),
    fnam: new FormControl(''),
    date: new FormControl(null),
  });
```

Hopefully this will save someone a few minutes in the future!

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I tried to access formGroup control like this

```
myFormGroup['controlName']
```

instead of using `.get('controlName')`. and btw If `.get('...')` is causing some typing problems, see this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67835904/8094012

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was passing simple property to `formControl` i.e.

```
tagsList: Array<string> = ['banana', 'apple']

<myComponent [formControl]="tagsList"></myComponent>
```

but **generally it should be like**

```
tagsList = new FormControl()

<myComponent [formControl]="tagsList"></myComponent>
```

**or**

```
tagsList: Array<string> = ['banana', 'apple']

<myComponent [(ngModel)]="tagsList"></myComponent>
```