# Error control.registerOnChange is not a function

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material, materialize

[image]

Can you suggest me what is the problem on this code? I want to display permsission_desc. Permssions :

```
[{"permissions":[{"permsission_id":1,"permsission_desc":"show"},...{...}]
```

my ts code:

```
      this.editRoleForm = this.fb.group({
              'sp_id': this.fb.array([ ]),
           });

  populateFormRole() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
      params => {
        this.rs.getRoleById(params['id']).subscribe(
          role => {
            this.role = role;
            this.role.permissions.forEach(permissions_id => {
              (this.editRoleForm.get('sp_id') as FormArray)
            .push(new FormControl(permissions_id.permission_id))
           })

          }
        )
      }
    );
  }
```

in html code

```
  <div class="row">
    <select multiple formControlName="sp_id" id="permission_id" materialize="material_select" [materializeSelectOptions]="permissions"
      [ngClass]="{invalid: invalidInputs}">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Select Permissions</option>
      <option *ngFor="let permission of permissions" [value]="permission.permission_id">{{permission.permissin_desc}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer from a related question help?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48345955/677737

Answer (score 0):

That would be

```
this.role.permissions.forEach(permissions_id: number => {
    (this.editRoleForm.get('sp_id') as FormArray)
        .push(new FormControl(permissions_id))
})
```

Comment: control.registerOnChange is not a function  --->       <select multiple formControlName="id" id="id" materialize="material_select" [materializeSelectOptions]="roles">  ---> In this part is the problem i think