# Close Angular Material mat-select multiselect with a button click?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I would like to have a multi-select dropdown menu where the user clicks an "apply" button (which is lives in the drop down) to close the menu. Using Angular Material and mat-select, is there a way to do this?

I'be already tried adding a close method to the button, but I get a lot of console errors, including "control.registerOnDisabledChange is not a function" and, after clicking, "control.markAsTouched is not a function"

```
 <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select #toppings placeholder="Toppings" [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingsList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
      <button (click)="toppings.close()">Apply</button>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

The list does close, but with the resulting console errors.

Comment: Aside from dangerous naming (the input _and_ formControl both have the name "toppings"), you need set up your reactive form properly. The issue is not with the button, but with `[formControl]="toppings"` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474011/what-causes-the-control-registeronchange-is-not-a-function-error. You may wish to use a FormGroup and access the `formControlName` in your template.

Answer (score 4):

As the comment mentions, there's naming collision. This works.

```
<mat-select #sl placeholder="Toppings" [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingsList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
        <button (click)="sl.close()">Apply</button>
    </mat-select>
```

Stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-material-primeng-template-1-hwuq4p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts