# Angular control.registerOnChange is not a function. Example link given

Tags: angular

I am facing an issue while loading form dynamically.
Example link given: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ubmufe

Click on clickone button and then click on clicktwo button, you will an find error in console.

If you click on the clickone button, refresh the app and click on clicktwo, the button is working.

Comment: Thanks for ur comments. I resolved this.

Answer (score 0):

I havent looked, to deply into your code yet, but this might be related:
[What causes the “control.registerOnChange is not a function” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474011/what-causes-the-control-registeronchange-is-not-a-function-error)

It errors, when you add a control to your FormGroup named `something` but there is no matching input wich has `formControlName="something"`

Answer (score 0):

That error message is a bit cryptic, but if you use FormBuilder, you would see this when you added a control to FormGroup in your component and named it differently, but then either forgot to add input with formControlName to your template, or formControlName for the intended input, or empty, or not present.

Basically, it says: "I cannot match the control I have in FormGroup to the control in the template".

Don't mix different formGroups/formControls/formArrays and better handle them in different variables.