# control.registerOnChange is not a function with ng-dynamic-forms and a custom form element

Tags: angular, angular-formbuilder

I am trying to use **ng-dynamic-forms** with a custom form element but I keep hitting that error :
control.registerOnChange is not a function

not sure what I am doing wrong

I have made a stackblitz here :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-dynamic-form-custom-control-registeronchange-error3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes the "control.registerOnChange is not a function" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474011/what-causes-the-control-registeronchange-is-not-a-function-error)

Comment: @dota2pro I went over all the SO questions mentionning "control.registerOnChange is not a function". The difference here is that I use ng-dynamic-forms. I believe that either the error comes frome inside of ng-dynamic-forms, or I am using it in a wrong manner. Since I am not sure this lib has an issue, I did a question here first.

Comment: Maybe its related to this still open Github Issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13788#issuecomment-274014852

Comment: @dota2pro it Could be yes. But I am not able to be sure for now, because there is ng-dynamic-forms between my code and angular.