# what is the best way to handle the onSelect data of select tag in reactive forms of angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular8

I want to know what is the best way to handle the below situation.
I have a form with couple of fields which include a select tag.

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <select formControlName="" >
    <option *ngFor="let c of countries" value="c"  (select)="onSelect(c)">{{c.name}}</option>
  </select>
</form>


export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private FormBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  public myForm: FormGroup;
  countries = [
    { id: 1, name: "United States" },
    { id: 2, name: "Australia" },
    { id: 3, name: "Canada" },
    { id: 4, name: "Brazil" },
    { id: 5, name: "England" },
  ];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.FormBuilder.group({
      country: new FormGroup({
        id: new FormControl("", []),
        name: new FormControl("", []),
      }),
    });
  }

  onSelect(option) {
  //tried this but not updating the myForm.value 
    this.myForm.controls['country'] = this.fb.group({
      id: new FormControl(event.detail.id, []),
      name: new FormControl(event.detail.name, [])
    });
  }
}
```

so my question is how should i map the selected value to the formObject.
And want to know a way of updating the myForm in onSelect(){}
how to specify the formControlName in select tag
or there is any simplified way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the setValue worked
**the below one was updating the controls but not the myForm.value object**

```js
onSelect(option) { 
//tried this but not updating the myForm.value 
this.myForm.controls['country'] = this.fb.group({ id: new FormControl(event.detail.id, []), name: new FormControl(event.detail.name, []) }); 
}

the below code worked
onSelect(option) { 
this.myForm.controls['country'].setValue({ id: event.detail.value, name: event.detail.description })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could bind to `change` event of the `select` tag and send in `myForm.value.country` as the argument. Try the following

Controller

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  myForm : FormGroup;
  countries = [
    {id: 1, name: "United States"},
    {id: 2, name: "Australia"},
    {id: 3, name: "Canada"},
    {id: 4, name: "Brazil"},
    {id: 5, name: "England"}
  ];

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.myForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      country: new FormGroup({
        id: new FormControl('', []),
        name: new FormControl('', [])
      })
    });
  }

  compareFn(c1: Country, c2: Country): boolean {
    return c1 && c2 ? c1.id === c2.id : c1 === c2;
  }

  onChange(option: any){
    console.log(option);
  }
}
```

Template

```html
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <select [compareWith]="compareFn" formControlName="country" (change)="onChange(myForm.value.country)">
    <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [ngValue]="country">
      {{ country.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
</form>

<p>Form value: </p>
<pre>{{ myForm.value | json }}</pre>
```

Working example: [**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-select-option-u96ssg)

BTW, you have two form controls `id` and `name` that aren't bound to any element in the template. So you'll get the error *control.registerOnChange is not a function*. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43463614/6513921).

Comment: Your answer looks pretty good. But i have a situation where am using the third party select component, which throws an event on select with the selected option. so how can i update the myForm with that.

Comment: i tried like this.myForm.controls['country'] = this.fb.group({
      id: new FormControl(event.detail.id, []),
      name: new FormControl(event.detail.name, [])
    });

Comment: It update the controls but it fails to update the myForm.value object

Comment: Could you please say which 'select' package you're using? We could try to use it in Stackblitz.

Comment: You still didn't say anything about the 3rd party component you were talking about.

Comment: its confidential bro. i cant reveal that. sorry for that

Comment: Then it isn't a third party component, it's an in-house solution. And without knowing how it emits the `select` event, it may be difficult to come up with a solution

Comment: but you can tell me how can i update myForm in onSelect event. because the selected option am getting as parameter in onselect event

Answer (score 1):

These are the two ways of doing it, and are best suited for most of the cases:
1- Using change Method like this:

```
(change)="onSelect(c)"
```

2- Using ngModelChange Method like this:

```
(ngModelChange)="onSelect(c)"
```

There are other ways of doing it, but it depend what you want to achieve.

> change method will be called only when you select any option.
>
> ngModelChange will be called anytime when your model's value gets changed. This is normally used when you have dependent fields. This should be used carefully. Whatever can be done using change method should be done using change method only.

Let's say if you want to populate values through an API call, you either explicitly bind every value or you can use [compareWith]

So it depends, everything exist due to some purpose. It's very much straight forward but still if you wish to see any example do let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Use `this.myForm.get("country").valueChanges` to detect the change of select dropdown.

Try like this:

.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.myForm = this.FormBuilder.group({
      country: new FormControl(null)
   });

   this.myForm.get("country").valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      console.log(value);
   });
 }
```

.html

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <select formControlName="country" >
    <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [value]="c.id"  >{{c.name}}</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

**[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-go1kvk?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: is there a way i can update the myForm in onSelect event

Comment: onSelect am getting the selected option in the event. Please refer to my question above. i want to update the id and name in the country in myForm

Comment: onSelect(option) {
  //tried this but not updating the myForm.value 
    this.myForm.controls['country'] = this.fb.group({
      id: new FormControl(event.detail.id, []),
      name: new FormControl(event.detail.name, [])
    });
  }

Comment: Why do you need `OnSelect` function?  `this.myForm.get("country").valueChanges` will solve the purpose

Comment: because my select component is a custom component which i cant reveal and i cant place and formControlName on it

Comment: It doesn't matter @AKRoy, the purpose of formControl is to handle any component. You could doit with the change output or with formControl (in the second option you find a problem, because you don't know about custom form control). I recommend it, to yours components.