# Source of “control.registerOnChange is not a function”

Tags: angular, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I've been through this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474011/what-causes-the-control-registeronchange-is-not-a-function-error) and can't seem to find my specific cause of this error. The best thing I can come up with is that I'm missing a `formControlName` or `formGroupName` somewhere in the template, but I can't find the underlying issue. I'm using Angular 8 reactive forms and `FormBuilder`.

My form is built as such:

```
this.recipeForm = this.fb.group({
    recipeName: (this.fb.control, null, Validators.required),
    recipeSource: (this.fb.control, null, Validators.required),
    recipeDescription: (this.fb.control, null, Validators.required),
    courseType: (this.fb.control, null, Validators.required),
    recipeIngredients: this.fb.array([]),
    recipeDirections: this.fb.array([]),
    tags: this.fb.array([])
  })
```

And I'm modifying the structure and adding fields like this:

```
/*********************************************************************************
* GET Ingredients FormArray
**********************************************************************************/
recipeIngredients(): FormArray {
  return this.recipeForm.get("recipeIngredients") as FormArray
}

/*********************************************************************************
* CREATE New Ingredient Section
**********************************************************************************/
newIngredientSection(): FormGroup {
  return this.fb.group({
    ingredientTitle: this.fb.control('', Validators.required),
    ingredients: this.fb.array([], Validators.required)
  })
}

/*********************************************************************************
* ADD New Ingredient Section
**********************************************************************************/  
addIngredientSection() {
  this.ingredientSections++;
  this.recipeIngredients().push(this.newIngredientSection());
  if (!this.editMode){
    this.addIngredient(this.ingredientSections);
  }
}

/*********************************************************************************
* REMOVE Ingredient Section
**********************************************************************************/  
removeIngredientSection(empIndex:number) {
  this.ingredientSections--;
  this.recipeIngredients().removeAt(empIndex);
}

/*********************************************************************************
* GET Ingredients Array
**********************************************************************************/
ingredients(empIndex:number) : FormArray {
  return this.recipeIngredients().at(empIndex).get("ingredients") as FormArray
}

/*********************************************************************************
* CREATE New Ingredient
**********************************************************************************/
newIngredient(): FormGroup {
  return this.fb.group({
    ingredient: ''
  }, Validators.required)
}

/*********************************************************************************
* ADD New Ingredient
**********************************************************************************/
addIngredient(empIndex:number) {
  this.ingredients(empIndex).push(this.newIngredient());
}

/*********************************************************************************
* REMOVE Section Ingredient
**********************************************************************************/
removeIngredient(empIndex:number, stepIndex:number) {
  this.ingredients(empIndex).removeAt(stepIndex);
}
```

And part of the form itself in the template:

```
<h4>Ingredients</h4>

  <div formArrayName="recipeIngredients">
  
    <div *ngFor="let ingredient of recipeIngredients().controls; let empIndex = index">
      <div [formGroupName]="empIndex">
      
      <button class="sectionBtn" (click)="removeIngredientSection(empIndex)">Remove Section</button>
  <div class="titleDiv">
    
      <mat-form-field class="mat-section-title" appearance="fill" >
          <mat-label>Title {{ empIndex + 1 }}</mat-label>
          <input required class="ingredient" matInput type="text" class="formControl" formControlName="ingredientTitle">
          <button type="button" *ngIf="this.recipeForm.get('recipeIngredients').value[empIndex].ingredientTitle !== ''"  class="close" mat-button  matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="clearIngredientTitle(empIndex);" >
            <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
          </button>
       </mat-form-field>
  </div>
  
        <div formArrayName="ingredients">
          <div *ngFor="let step of ingredients(empIndex).controls; let stepIndex = index">
            <div [formGroupName]="stepIndex">
            <mat-form-field class="mat-section-step" appearance="outline" >
              <mat-label>Ingredient {{stepIndex + 1}} </mat-label>
              <textarea required class="steps" matInput type="text" cdkTextareaAutosize #autosize="cdkTextareaAutosize" formControlName="ingredient"> </textarea>
              <button type="button" *ngIf="getIngredient(empIndex, stepIndex) === false" class="close" mat-button  matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="Clear" (click)="clearIngredient(empIndex, stepIndex);" >
                <mat-icon>close</mat-icon>
              </button>
            </mat-form-field>
  
              <button class="stepBtn" (click)="removeIngredient(empIndex, stepIndex)">Remove</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
  
        <button class="ingredientBtn" type="button" (click)="addIngredient(empIndex)"> Add Ingredient </button>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
      </div>
  
    </div>
  
    <button class="ingredientBtn" type="button" (click)="addIngredientSection()">Add Ingredient Section</button>
  
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
  
   </div>
```

The only thing I can think of like I mentioned at the start is that I might be missing `formControlName` or `formGroupName` in the template due to my functions that modify the form adding formGroups that don't have a name, and if that is the case I'm not sure how to go about naming them to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After rebuilding the entire form page from scratch, bit by bit adding in the original code, I was able to find out what was causing the error. The error line number is very misleading, and has nothing to do with the actual cause. In a section of code not shown in the question, I have a `mat-chip-list`:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-chip-list" >
                <mat-chip-list #chipList aria-label="Add Tags" formControlName="tags">
                  <mat-chip *ngFor="let tag of tags" [selectable]="selectable" [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(tag)">
                      {{ tag }}
                      <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
                  </mat-chip>
                  <input placeholder="Add tags separated by space"
                         [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
                         [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
                         [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
                         (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)"
                         >
                </mat-chip-list>
              </mat-form-field>
```

For whatever reason, removing the `formControlName="tags"` from the `mat-chip-list` fixes the error. Even adding `formControlName="tags"` on the input (which is where it should have been initially anyway) causes the code to throw the error on a completely unrelated line, typically a line with `*ngFor`, and once those have been removed, on inputs and buttons, and finally on the opening form tag itself. Hopefully this can help someone else in the future.