# How to validate multiple select boxes in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, validation, ionic-framework, angular-forms

Here's the scenario. I have a huge chunk of data that has information about a product. The product has various options available without selecting all of them the user shouldn't be allowed to add the product to the cart or buy. Here's the code I have tried.

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
    'options': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
});
```

This works fine but after selecting only 1 option the user is allowed to click on the add to cart button, I want to restrict that feature. I think I need to implement [formArray](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray). But I'm stuck here. I'll appreciate any help.

Here's the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-ksihmr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) for more details

Comment: Is this you looking for https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-tfaiiw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Let me know if anything missing. Is your expected output from fromGroup? I will add an answer if you confirm

Comment: Sure, I'll look that up in an hour and revert back. Thank you for your time and effort

Comment: Everything's working fine except I'm getting the options from API but we're initiating the controls on onInit is there anyway we can set async function ?

Comment: Share code where you are using service in your component to get options

Comment: shall I update in my stackblitz?

Comment: Yeah you canadd it there

Comment: sure give me a minute

Comment: I have updated in my stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-ksihmr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: That it, https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-qbsgjq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts... If you want i can help you optimize your code more further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize your form as

```
  initForm() {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      options: new FormArray([]),
    });
  }
```

Helpers methods to get or set options

```
  set setOptionsFA(controls: FormControl[]) {
    controls.forEach((control) => this.optionsFA.push(control));
  }

  get optionsFA(): FormArray {
    return this.form.get('options') as FormArray;
  }

  get optionsControls(): FormControl[] {
    return this.optionsFA.controls as FormControl[];
  }
```

method to create `FormControl[]` out of your options list

```
  createOptionControls(options: any[]): FormControl[] {
    return options.map(
      (_) => new FormControl(null, Validators.required)
    ) as FormControl[];
  }
```

Use RxJs [tap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/tap) operator to call `createOptionsControls` method and pass options to it and set FormArray options

```
 this.appService
  .productDetail(247)
  .pipe(
    tap(
      ({ options }) =>
        (this.setOptionsFA = this.createOptionControls(options))
    )
  )
  .subscribe((res) => {
    this.data = res;
  });
```

[Angular Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-qbsgjq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I get `ERROR TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function` this error but it is working in stackblitz what could be the problem. Although I referred this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474011/what-causes-the-control-registeronchange-is-not-a-function-error

Comment: At what line the error is? Can you produce on stackblitz. What's your angular version? Have you updated in template like `[formControl]="optionsControls[i]"`

Comment: I'm using `angular 11.2.0`, I'll try if I can make it to stackblitz

Comment: Did the issue resolved?

Comment: yes sorry forgot to inform you. Thanks btw

Comment: I already did thanks for your support I appreciate it :) have a good day